# I need help finding this question: How to simulate one large file out of many segments?

Tags: support, search

I know this question has already been asked, so asking it again would make it a doublon.

But I can not remember how exactly that question was phrased, so I am unable to find it.

It was about simulating one virtual large file out of many small parts of an image file, without actually creating that file. Linux just acts as if the image file exists as one big file.

Comment: Are you looking for [your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425093/simuate-one-large-file-out-of-multiple-small-segmential-files) which got closed as a dupe of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/a-virtual-file-containing-the-concatenation-of-other-files)?

Comment: Yes, @AndrewT. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ask the question. If it is indeed a duplicate, it will be closed as a duplicate, and will will have one more way of finding it next time someone has the same issue.

That's the simplest way of finding it and having your question as well as the existing one will make it easier next time.